# c# mimecontent to filestream

Tags: c#, sharepoint, filestream

I am trying to download .eml files (message.mimecontent) from an Exchange Server and upload it to a SharePoint document library. One option is saving the file to local drive and then uploading it from a filestream.

Is there a way that I can convert mimecontent to a filestream without saving it as a file first ? This would make the code much nicer avoiding all intricacies of file operations, file name management etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using EWS, the mime content is actually a byte[]. See the [Content property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.mimecontent.content(v=exchg.80).aspx).

Without saving this byte[] to the file system, keep it in memory, and use [this SPFileCollection.Add method overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms367739) to upload a file to the SharePoint site by providing the byte[] as input.